# Please explain this CSS

Tags: html, css

I've noticed this code when I viewed page source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css:style.css" />
```

It doesn't make sense to me. "css" is not a valid URL to an external CSS file. The developer said something like this:
"It is reserved for the file > css/custom.css"

I still don't understand. Please, explain it to me if you know about such a code.

Comment: Is this a _page_ source (post-parsing) or a _template_ source (pre-parsing)? Because AFAIK, this "URL" is invalid. But you if this is on a live website somewhere, you could check the "Network" tab in the dev tools, where that URL should either show up as a 404, or show the full URL if the browser indeed resolves it.

Answer (score 4):

The `css:style.css` is probably a placeholder that will later get replaced with the actual URL to `style.css` by [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or some other project automation tool.

It's a common practise with code reprocessors such as [`gulp-inject`](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject).

Comment: Okay, so I can just leave it as is and I shouldn't be worried?

Here's the place where you can see it, BTW:

view-source:http://demo.joomlaplates.com/jp_x2

Comment: Yes, that's probably replaced automaticaly when rendering the page.

Comment: They also said:

The missing URL for the custom.css depends on the php code to include the css file.
If there is no css file to load, the code is blank"
>> layouts/theme.config.php  `$this->addFile('css', 'css:custom.css');
`   I found this line of PHP code in template.config.php  `$this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:custom.css');
`

Comment: I don't know Joomla so I can't help you with it.